Suggestions for image region separation
I have some SEM images that I need to process,all those images have extra information in the bottom of the images as can be seen in the red bounding box. I need to remove those portion before doing the later processing.

Is there any library that can accomplish this task, automatically divide the image into two distinct regions? I know I can train some ML model to do this task but if there is some pre-trained ML library like yolo that would be great for me. The position of the extra portion varies, sometimes it is in the bottom, sometimes on the right side but there are mostly same.

Can you share more examples? Is the size of the section constant? Are the image dimensions constant?

Hi, thanks for the reply. Apparently, the size of the section was constant as well as the image dimensions. So I was able to solve them without any issue.
